# Can I map blender with a MIDI controller?

Tags: interface

Can I use a MIDI controller to map blender's interface so that it becomes faster?

I tried with some MIDI translator, but I'd like to not have to use external software.

Comment: Midi2key with loopmidi might be what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does "external software" include Blender add-ons? There are a few for MIDI in and out event detection. i.e. "Add MIDI" http://www.jpfep.net/pages/addmidi/ ;

I don't think you can map MIDI controllers without add-ons or at least a python script.

Comment: what other midi addons do you know about? I haven't been able to find any, and that one doesn't provide time synchronization.